# How to add photos to Vue Carousel 3D slider correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm trying to figure out the Vue Carousel 3D [documentation](https://wlada.github.io/vue-carousel-3d/examples/) and can't figure out how to get one image displayed on each slide. Let me explain: I want to make a slider like in the documentation in the Controls Customized example.

There is such a construction

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    slides: 8
  },
  components: {
    'carousel-3d': window['carousel-3d'].Carousel3d,
    'slide': window['carousel-3d'].Slide
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="example">
  <carousel-3d :controls-visible="true" :controls-prev-html="'❬ '" :controls-next-html="'❭'" :controls-width="30" :controls-height="60" :clickable="false">
    <slide v-for="(slide, i) in slides" :index="i">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://placehold.it/360x270">
      </figure>
    </slide>
  </carousel-3d>
</div>
```

[As in the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDFOo.jpg)

But when I tried to use the construction, as in the example, I got it like this, and as a result, sliders with the same picture are displayed. I also did not understand what is: index = "i". I thought it was the priority of pictures, but I was wrong.

```html
<div id="example">
  <carousel-3d :controls-visible="true" :controls-prev-html="'&#10092; '" :controls-next-html="'&#10093;'" :controls-width="30" :controls-height="60" :clickable="false">
    <slide v-for="(slide, i) in slides" :index="i">
      <figure>
        <img src="/img/sliders/1.jpg">
      </figure>
    </slide>
    <slide v-for="(slide, i) in slides" :index="i">
      <figure>
        <img src="/img/sliders/2.jpg">
      </figure>
    </slide>
    <slide v-for="(slide, i) in slides" :index="i">
      <figure>
        <img src="/img/sliders/3.jpg">
      </figure>
    </slide>
    <slide v-for="(slide, i) in slides" :index="i">
      <figure>
        <img src="/img/sliders/4.jpg">
      </figure>
    </slide>
    <slide v-for="(slide, i) in slides" :index="i">
      <figure>
        <img src="/img/sliders/5.jpg">
      </figure>
    </slide>
    <slide v-for="(slide, i) in slides" :index="i">
      <figure>
        <img src="/img/sliders/6.jpg">
      </figure>
    </slide>
    <slide v-for="(slide, i) in slides" :index="i">
      <figure>
        <img src="/img/sliders/7.jpg">
      </figure>
    </slide>

  </carousel-3d>
</div>
```

[As in the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVxJh.jpg)

[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIeFl.jpg)

I also tried to use several figure tags in the slider tag, enclosing pictures in the figure, but again, not that. Help me figure it out, please!
The site itself http://c96180og.beget.tech/

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `v-for` is to loop through some bound data, so multiple `v-for` would defeat the reasoning behind that.  Instead, change `slides` to an array.  For example, an array of objects containing some image data:

```js
slides: [
   { id: 1, src: '/img/sliders/1.jpg' },
   { id: 2, src: '/img/sliders/2.jpg' },
   { id: 3, src: '/img/sliders/3.jpg' },
   { id: 4, src: '/img/sliders/4.jpg' },
   { id: 5, src: '/img/sliders/5.jpg' },
   { id: 6, src: '/img/sliders/6.jpg' },
   { id: 7, src: '/img/sliders/7.jpg' },
]
```

<sup>An example using an array of objects with an `id` and `src` property.  You could use an array of just the `src` strings if you prefer.</sup>

Now these can be rendered using a single `v-for`:

```html
<slide v-for="(slide, i) in slides" :index="i">
   <figure>
      <img :src="slide.src">
   </figure>
</slide>
```

The `index` attribute is a prop on that component which refers to the `index` in the loop.